# You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled after last react native upgrade

Tags: xcode, react-native

Just upgraded react native from 0.61.4 to 0.63.0-rc using [rn diff](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.4&to=0.63.0-rc.1)

Now when I run the app with Xcode I get this unusual error

```
ld: '{projet-path}/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a(bio_lib.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've checked and bitcode is enabled in the Xcode settings, but what's intriguing is that there's no mention of OpenSSL in the podfile

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution for this problem?